# protobuf.net De-Serializer waits indefinitely

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have got a simple TCPlistener that listens for connections and once a connection has been established, a method tries to send data and the server side tries to read it.

client side:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(_client.Client, false))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, MyPersonObject);
            }
```

Server side:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(_client.Client, false))
            {
                var myObject = Serializer.DeSerialize<Person>(stream);
            }
```

However, I've noticed that once it hits the DeSerialize method, it hangs and waits indefinitely.
**Note that this does NOT happen with BinaryFormatter using the exact same steps.** I am not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A protobuf stream is not "closed" - it reads until the end of the stream by default, which means it will read until the inbound TCP socket is mark as complete.

If you intend to send multiple messages, try using the "WithLengthPrefix" versions of serialize and deserialize; that adds message framing for you, allowing it to know where each payload ends.

Comment: Hello Marc. Are you saying that it waits indefinitely because the TCP socket is not marked as complete? What do you mean by "Marked as complete"? If it reads until the end of the steam, shouldn't it go out after that? I have tried it with Memory-stream and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @Enlight in this context, I mean that the incoming receive socket (the send socket of the source) would need to have been closed. Otherwise, the stream is open. To send multiple messages on a socket, you need framing; which is what "WithLengthPrefix" provides. By contrast BinaryFormatter had framing inbuilt, which is fine: but the protobuf format is defined by Google, not me - so I don't get to add it unilaterally :) if you are only sending one message: just close the send pipe after writing.

Comment: @Enlight the reason for this is that the actual [encoding format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) allows for messages longer or shorter than the actual object you expected (e.g. for "unknown fields" from a later version of the protocol, or merged fields). If you don't have a Length Marker, the decoder doesn't know if you're still expecting more data in the stream while it's still open.

Comment: And you said it worked fine when using a MemoryStream; that's because a Memory (and File) Stream have a known [Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.length#System_IO_MemoryStream_Length) (i.e. a defined "end" to the stream). A NetworkStream [has no defined Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.length#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_Length); and unless you close it, there's no way for the system to know the data has finished.

Comment: By length, do you mean message framing as well? a byte gets sent over to tell the receiver how many bytes are in the following message? And since there is no message framing in NetworkStream, you're able to send only one thing and then have to close the socket for the receiver to get

Comment: @Enlight not really. By length, I meant that some streams intrinsically have finite size and an end. A FileStream knows exactly how big the file is. A MemoryStream has a reserved size of the memory block. *Message framing* is embedding the length in the message itself. You can combine it with the other known-length streams. Say you have a 5KB file, within it you can have multiple frames. Each of them could embed a length e.g. message1 is 2KB, message2 is 3KB, etc. Having framing in the message makes them independent from the stream length.

Comment: Right, so having message framing in every message sent tells the receiver as to exactly how big every message is, so it knows exactly that it should receive the data even without the stream having a  defined length. I wonder why there is no length to a NetworkStream.

Comment: @Enlight Having length is actually a bonus. There are probably more streams *without* a defined length than those with. Imagine a... stream. All you can see is the fact that water is flowing in it. You usually have no idea when the water will stop (in some streams, it's during summer. In others, never). A lot of `Stream` derivatives have no known length because they need to be kept open and data can just come whenever they feel like. Through the network, or USB cable, radio waves, etc. Unless the data itself tells you how big it's going to be, you'll never know how much more is coming.

Comment: Makes sense. Unless you have message framing, you will have no idea how big the data is. Thanks for explaining

Comment: @NPras Sorry for the very very late message, but I was kind of reviewing this and a question popped into my head. If a MemoryStream has a defined length (amount of ram) and Protobuf's Serializer has no message framing which means that the receiver(MemoryStream) has no idea how big it is, then..  why does it work?

Comment: @Enlight  Technically you *could* run into the same framing issue with a memory stream if you're simultaneously reading and writing into it. But `MemoryStream` is not thread-safe, so it's not meant to be read and written simultaneously anyway. Usually the writer would signal that it's finished writing. The reader then knows that whatever's in there and how big it is once the writer has finished.

Comment: @Enlight a memorystream knows how many bytes it contains, so it can indicate EOF when you reach the end; other "open" streams like NetworkStream, SslStream, etc: cannot (at least, usually; there are some conditions when they can), so they block indefinitely (or timeout, which isn't the same as EOF)

Comment: Even though the normal serialize method has no framing built in, MemoryStream can still process it because it can read until the end of the stream?, while in the otherhand, it cannot read until the end with a NetworkStream because there's no end essentially.?

Comment: @Enlight exactly; you can't detect the end of a `NetworkStream` unless the other end shuts down their outbound socket meaning no more data will *ever* arrive; or putting it another way, you *can* do this with `NetworkStream` *if* you send exactly one frame and close the outbound - then the receiver can just read until EOF on their inbound

Comment: @MarcGravell Makes sense, however, is framing, or message framing only used for network sockets/packets? If yes, that'd make more sense as to why I can deserialize on a ```MemoryStream```. Because if there's no framing(length of the data) how come I can deserialize on a ```MemoryStream```, or yet how can it tell that the message is completed and not partially sent, as opposed to a NetworkStream, where if each packet does not have the length of the whole message, then you have to close it to indicate that the data is finished.

Comment: @Enlight no, it is used in other contexts - anywhere where you want to convey more than one payload, rather than saying "just read until you run out of data to read". You can deserialize from a `MemoryStream` because it reports EOF when it hits the end of the data that it contains

Comment: @MarcGravell EOF as in, it reads until the end of the stream? Regardless of that though, if the serializer doesn't have framing, if it reads the data until the end of the stream, it wouldn't know if it's partial or not. I might be missing something.

Comment: @Enlight indeed you wouldn't; yet that isn't actually a problem in all cases - files don't get truncated that often, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell So, let's take ```MemoryStream``` for example. If we say that it reserved a block of memory in advance, and we serialize something to it that has no framing, I assume that it wouldn't care that it doesn't have data length, and will just get added to the block of memory. In the other hand, since ```NetworkStream``` doesn't have a defined length(no place to put the data?), I assume the data will just hang out somewhere in the socket or in an internal buffer?

Comment: @Enlight `MemoryStream` is skewing your thinking here; streams are "pipes", not "buckets" - they don't usually *contain anything* - they're more an API to *get* something. The fact that `MemoryStream` *actually has the bytes* is a leaky implementation detail of `MemoryStream`. However, you should instead focus on "can data be fetched?" - on a `NetworkStream`, if there isn't anything buffered locally, then the answer is "I don't know yes or no until I see either some more bytes, or the socket closes"; a `MemoryStream` can answer more definitely right away, hence it doesn't cause a blockage.

Comment: @MarcGravell The pipe vs bucket is a good analogy. The quirk is that with `MemoryStream`, the pipe *is* attached to a bucket and - coupled with the fact that a memory stream is contained within the process - you (the process) are sitting right next to the bucket and can actually see how much water is in it. With a `NetworkStream`, the pipe is attached to the mains; and unless the other party told you they've shut the mains, you don't know if there's more water coming.